# Flask POST endpoint not receiving arguments with curl

Tags: python, flask

I have this simple flask app with one endpoint and I am trying to receive data from a POST request in curl. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/shipment", methods=["POST"])
    def hello_world():
        if "start" in request.args:
            return "arg found"
        else:
            return "missing args"

    return app
```

`curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:5000/shipment -d start="test"`

Answer (score 1):

`request.args` can only retrieve key/value pair in the URL. You need to check `request.values` instead.